# Silverlight WCF with two-way SSL security certificates

Tags: wcf, silverlight, ssl, ssl-certificate, wcf-security

I would like to implement a server - client software with the following security requirements:

- WCF-Services need to be secured with SSL and Certificates for both, the server and the client
- Client certificates need to be generated programmatically upon user registration
- Client-certificates are deployed via a an automatically generated installer-package
- Altough the client-certificates are self-signed (no authorized CA for the generation server) the end-user must not add the server-certificate to the trusted certificates in the local Certificate Store

My problems:
I cannot find any information regarding establishing such a two-way ssl-security for wcf, while the server-certificate is not signed by an authorized CA and instead is created programmatically with "makecert"...

My question:
Is it technically possible to implement this requirements? If yes - could you provide some hints how to get started?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're trying to do alot of complicated stuff here, with the certificates in particular. Have you considered using Username/Password system instead for client credentials? With the server cert, if it's not a valid SSL certificate, you can bypass the certificate validation by the client using config like:

```
    <behavior name="DisableServiceCertificateValidation">
      <clientCredentials>
        <serviceCertificate>
          <authentication certificateValidationMode="None"
                          revocationMode="NoCheck" />
        </serviceCertificate>
      </clientCredentials>
    </behavior>
```

Compare your requirements (might be best to start simple) to the Application Scenarios / How Tos sections of this [CodePlex link](http://wcfsecurity.codeplex.com/). You will then be able to work through the configuration and setup guides to get you up and running, giving you something you can build upon.